# Adjust font size based on text length and window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to adjust the text size depending on the length of text inside the element title. This works great until the user adjusts the size of the browser. What can be done to allow the text size to be adjusted if the user's window is made smaller. Say for instance if window width is less than 600 pixels, than change font size.

How can this be made to on page load, do what the code does now - but also change font sizes when browser size is adjusted as well?

```
$(".title").css('font-size', function () { // get length of text for title and adjust font size
    var $numWords = $(this).text().length;
    if (($numWords >= 1) && ($numWords < 40)) {
        return "26px";
    }
    else if (($numWords >= 40) && ($numWords < 60)) {
        return "24px";
    }
    else if (($numWords >= 60) && ($numWords < 100)) {
        return "22px";
    }
    else if (($numWords >= 100)) {
        return "20px";
    }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you would want to give [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/) a try? It does exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="cont" style="font-family: Verdana; background-color: #ccc;">
    <div id="textContent">fox jump over the lazy dog...fox jump over the lazy dog...fox jump over the lazy dog</div>
</div>  
<script>
    var textContainer = document.getElementById('cont');
    var text = document.getElementById('textContent');
    var textLength = text.innerText.length;
    var firstLoadWidth;

    if (textLength >= 1 && textLength < 40) {
        cont.style.fontSize = '26px';
    }
    else if (textLength >= 1 && textLength < 60) {
        cont.style.fontSize = '24px';
    }
    else if (textLength >= 1 && textLength < 100) {
        cont.style.fontSize = '22px';
    }
    else if (textLength > 100) {
        cont.style.fontSize = '20px';
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        firstLoadWidth = window.innerWidth;
    });
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        var getSize = window.innerWidth / firstLoadWidth;
        getSize <= 1 ? text.style.fontSize = getSize + 'em' : text.style.fontSize = '1em';
    }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `resize()` function for that (http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    onResize()
});

onResize = function() {
    if(window.width() < 600){
        // Do stuff
     }
}

$(window).bind('resize', onResize);
```

Comment: OK, how could I combine the resize function, but also have the page set the font size on the inital load before a resize event?

Comment: By calling the same function onload as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the actual rendered size of the text like this:

```
var text = $(this).text();
var tmp = $("<div/>").css({position: "absolute"}).text(text);
$("BODY").append(tmp);
var width = tmp.width();
tmp.remove();
```

If you make sure your `div` is styled as it will be on the page (same font, weight, size), then this can tell you how big it will be. It should be possible to iterate this to search for a size that fits the available space (with some reasonable cutoff). This will be slow if you have hundreds or thousands of these on a page, but for a couple of titles it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

just use the percentage in your font-size

```
p {
font-size:200%;
}
```

the percentage is due to the width of the parent tags "div"